# Habilitar campos de formulário com JS com Radio Button

Tags: php, javascript, html, lavarel

Estou iniciando com Javascript e tenho um pequeno problema.

Tenho um formulário em HTML onde tenho um campo `radio` onde tenho duas opções, `Texto` e `Página`. Quando eu clicar na opção `Texto` ele carrega um campo  `input` para inserir o titulo, quando eu seleciono o `Página` ele me mostra dois campos um `input` com titulo e subtitulo.

Como eu faria essa logica?

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="title-type" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Tipo Título:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input name="title-type" type="radio" value="text" id="title-type" onclick="typeRadioButton()"> Texto
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input name="title-type" type="radio" value="page" id="title-type" onclick="typeRadioButton()"> Página
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    {{ Form::label('metadata', 'Título', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 col-form-label']) }}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control',  'placeholder' => 'Digite um Titulo', 'required' => true]) }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    {{ Form::label('metadata', 'Sub-título', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 col-form-label']) }}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ Form::text('pagetitle', null, ['class' => 'form-control',  'placeholder' => 'Digite um Sub-Titulo', 'required' => true]) }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    {{ Form::label('metadata', 'Conteúdo', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 col-form-label']) }}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ Form::textarea('slot', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => true]) }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    {{ Form::label('metadata', 'Cor de fundo:', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 col-form-label']) }}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ Form::checkbox('Usar Padrão do site', '', false) }} Usar Padrão do site
        <input type="color" name="background ">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    {{ Form::label('metadata', 'Cor do título:', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 col-form-label']) }}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ Form::checkbox('Usar Padrão do site', '', false) }} Usar Padrão do site
        <input type="color" name="color-title">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    {{ Form::label('metadata', 'Cor do texto:', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 col-form-label']) }}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ Form::checkbox('Usar Padrão do site', '', false) }} Usar Padrão do site
        <input type="color" name="color-text">
    </div>
</div>


{{-- JQuert--}}
<script>
    function typeRadioButton() {
        var type = document.getElementsByName("title-type");

        if (type[0].checked) {
            alert('Text');

        } else if (type[1].checked) {
            alert('Page');
        }
    }

</script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se você quer uma solução em Javascript, seria melhor você postar o html renderizado em sua pergunta.

Comment: Beleza, está ai colocado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deverá ser algo deste género, depois metendo nas divs com `id="inv"` e `id="inv2"` os inputs que pretende que apareçam consoante o botão que está premido.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#global').bind("keyup click", function() {
    hideShow();
  });
  hideShow();
});


function hideShow() {
  if ($('#texto').is(':checked')) {
    $('#inv').show();
  } else {
    $('#inv').hide();
  }
  if ($('#pagina').is(':checked')) {
    $('#inv2').show();
  } else {
    $('#inv2').hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row" id="global">
  <label for="title-type" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Tipo Título:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input name="title-type" type="radio" value="text" id="texto"> Texto
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input name="title-type" type="radio" value="page" id="pagina"> Página
  </div>
</div>
<div style="diplay: none;" id="inv">
  Coisas escondidas
</div>
<div style="diplay: none;" id="inv2">
  Outras Cenas escondidas
</div>
```

Comment: Valeu cara, muito obrigado!